# Flask is working but Flask with nginx is not working

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am running Flask and it is working fine, Flask is running in host (Not Container),

I can access flask application with bellow url

```
   http://1.1.1.3:5000/lsinfo?id=1&subid=wyyys
```

Now I have to use nginx, and I am running nginx with container. Below is Docker and nginx file

```
    FROM nginx:1.15.2

    RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  3;

events { }

http {

  keepalive_timeout  360s;

  server {

      listen 80;
      server_name example.com hostname.examplae.com;
      charset utf-8;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://1.1.1.3:5000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
  }
}
```

I am running with below command

```
 docker run -d --name nginx-service -p 8080:80 image/nginx
```

But I am unable to access through nginx, I am trying like below

```
  http://1.1.1.3:8080/lsinfo?id=1&subid=wyyys
```

Anything I am doing wrong in nginx.conf file, or I need to mention location too? flask url is ip:5000/lsinfo and that need id and subid inputs

Note: Both are running in same network

Comment: Your docker container and flask is not on the same network.

Comment: same network and running in same host

Comment: In this example, 1.1.1.3 is one of the host's IP addresses?

Comment: Yes thats the host IP address